Volumable buttons with Jetpack Compose
How to implement a volumable buttons with Jetpack Compose like this?

There are two shadows: black shadow at top and white shadow at bottom.
This is how that button described in Figma:

This is how I try to create that button in code:
@Composable
fun GameCoinsView(
  modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
  coins: Int,
  onClick: () -> Unit = {},
) {
  Box(
    modifier = modifier
      .clip(shape = shape)
      .width(IntrinsicSize.Min)
      .height(IntrinsicSize.Min)
  ) {
    Spacer(
      modifier = Modifier
        .align(Alignment.BottomCenter)
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .fillMaxHeight(fraction = 0.95f)
        .shadow(
          elevation = 2.dp,
          shape = RoundedCornerShape(12.dp),
          spotColor = Color.White.copy(alpha = 0.08f),
        ),
    )
    Spacer(
      modifier = Modifier
        .align(Alignment.TopCenter)
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .fillMaxHeight(fraction = 0.95f)
        .shadow(
          elevation = 2.dp,
          shape = RoundedCornerShape(12.dp),
          spotColor = Color.Black.copy(alpha = 0.28f),
        ),
    )
    Spacer(
      modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .background(color = Color.White.copy(alpha = 0.08f))
        .blur(40.dp),
    )

    Text(
      modifier = Modifier.padding(vertical = 8.dp, horizontal = 12.dp),
      text = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(ViewUtils.getDefaultLocaleCompose()).format(coins),
      fontSize = 18.sp,
      lineHeight = 23.4.sp,
      fontWeight = FontWeight.W600,
    )
  }
}

The result of my code is:


You can create an inner shadow with composed Modifier to save Paint for recomopsition while adding blur with framworkPaint's xferMode
frameworkPaint.apply {
    xfermode = PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_OUT)
    maskFilter =
        BlurMaskFilter(blurRadius.toPx(), BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL)
}

It also has other selections for blur type
public static enum Blur {
    NORMAL,
    SOLID,
    OUTER,
    INNER;

Define Modifier as
fun Modifier.innerShadow(
    shape: Shape,
    color: Color = Color.Black,
    x: Dp = 2.dp,
    y: Dp = 2.dp,
    blurRadius: Dp = 4.dp,
) = composed {
    val paint = remember {
        Paint()
    }

    println("Paint: $paint")

    drawWithContent {
        drawContent()

        val outline = shape.createOutline(size, layoutDirection, this)

        paint.color = color

        with(drawContext.canvas) {
            saveLayer(size.toRect(), paint)

            drawOutline(outline, paint)

            val frameworkPaint = paint.asFrameworkPaint()

            frameworkPaint.apply {
                xfermode = PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_OUT)
                maskFilter =
                    BlurMaskFilter(blurRadius.toPx(), BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL)
            }

            paint.color = Color.Black

            translate(x.toPx(), y.toPx())
            drawOutline(outline, paint)

            frameworkPaint.xfermode = null
            frameworkPaint.maskFilter = null
            restore()
        }
    }
}

Demo
@Preview
@Composable
fun Test() {

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color(0xff00796B))
            .padding(16.dp)
    ) {

        var blurRadiusWhite by remember {
            mutableFloatStateOf(5f)
        }

        var blurRadiusBlack by remember {
            mutableFloatStateOf(4f)
        }

        Text("Blur white: $blurRadiusWhite")


        Slider(
            value = blurRadiusWhite,
            onValueChange = {
                blurRadiusWhite = it
            },
            valueRange = 1f..20f
        )

        Text("Blur black: $blurRadiusBlack")
        Slider(
            value = blurRadiusBlack,
            onValueChange = {
                blurRadiusBlack = it
            },
            valueRange = 1f..20f
        )


        Row(
            modifier  = Modifier
                .innerShadow(
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp),
                    color = Color.White.copy(.8f),
                    x = (-2).dp,
                    y = (-2).dp,
                    blurRadius = blurRadiusWhite.dp
                )
                .innerShadow(
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp),
                    color = Color.Black,
                    x = 2.dp,
                    y = 2.dp,
                    blurRadius = (blurRadiusBlack).dp
                )
                .background(Color(0xff009688), RoundedCornerShape(16.dp))
                .padding(16.dp)
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "Hello World",
                fontSize = 30.sp,

                )
        }
    }
}

Result

